# When does MySQL server start when my system starts up?

Tags: startup, mysql

I installed MySQL using `apt-get ...`, and when I press the power button, while my system boot up, MySQL starts automatically. But I want to know what's the time it starts exactly, and through which script the `mysqld` is invoked?

Answer (score 0):

For recent Ubuntu versions, in `/etc/init/mysql.conf` you'll find the Upstart configuration for the MySQL service. [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) is the init daemon to initialize and boot the system after your kernel and initramfs are finished.

As Upstart is event-driven and based on dependencies, you can't tell exactly in what order and what time a service is started, but you can change the dependencies in the `start on` directive. I suggest you to read more about Upstart in case you want to do modification in this.